# Как заменить ветку на другую в gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

Как в gitlab заменить содержимое ветки develop другой веткой?

Есть ветка develop. 
Есть ветка newDevelop.

Как превратить newDevelop в develop?

Comment: переименовать? смержить?

Comment: А переименование никак на gitlab не отразиться? 
Там же используется ветка develop по умолчанию в проекте

Comment: ветка в программе *git* — это всего лишь указатель на коммит. просто переставьте указатели на нужные коммиты. не забудьте, что если пользователей у хранилища больше одного — будет чехарда и неразбериха. // p.s. как называется программа, которая отрисовывает веб-модру — gitlab/gitbla/blabla/bumbum — роли здесь абсолютно никакой не играет.

Comment: А force push как то может повлиять на gitlab? Там ведь хранятся старые merge request с коммитами которые исчезнут при откате назад.